# cant get exponent to work in my calculator

Tags: python, calculator

This is my first time doing anything in python...or any other programming language at all really.

Below is my first try at a simple calculator:

```
print ("Hello")
def calc():
    x = int(input("Input first integer: "))
    y = int(input("Input second integer: "))
    type = str.lower(input("(A)dd, (S)ubstract, (M)ultiply, (D)ivide \n"))
    if type != "a" and type != "s" and type != "m" and type != "d":
        print ("Sorry, the command you entered is not valid.")
        calc()
    else:
        if type =="a":
            print ("The result is '" + str(x+y) + "'")
        elif type == "s":
            print ("The result is '" + str(x-y) + "'")
        elif type =="m":
            print ("The result is '" + str(x*y) + "'")
        elif type == "d":
            print ("The result is '" + str(float(x)/float(y)) + "'")

        if int(input("Enter 1 if you would like to perform another calculation? \n")) == 1:
            calc()
        else:
            exit()
calc()
```

That seems to work ok. Next I tried to add exponent and remainder into the mix and I get a syntax error.

```
print ("Hello")
def calc():
    x = int(input("Input first integer: "))
    y = int(input("Input second integer: "))
    type = str.lower(input("(A)dd, (S)ubstract, (M)ultiply, (D)ivide,       (E)xponent,      (R)emainder\n"))
if type != "a" and type != "s" and type != "m" and type != "d" and type != "e" and type != "r":
    print ("Sorry, the command you entered is not valid.")
    calc()
else:
    if type == "a":
        print ("The result is '" + str(x+y) + "'")
    elif type == "s":
        print ("The result is '" + str(x-y) + "'")
    elif type == "m":
        print ("The result is '" + str(x*y) + "'")
    elif type == "d":
        print ("The result is '" + str(float(x)/float(y)) + "'")
    elif type == "e":
        print ("The result is '" + str(x**y + "'")
    elif type == "r":
        print ("The result is '" + str(x%y) + "'")

    if int(input("Enter 1 if you would like to perform another calculation? \n")) == 1:
        calc()
    else:
        exit()
calc()
```

Is there something simple I'm doing incorrectly?
Also, I need to add a "Q" to quit...can anyone refer me to something that will explain the process more simply?

Comment: You should not name your variable one of Python's key words.  type is a reserved or key word.  You might replace type with operation or something more descriptive

Answer (score 1):

`print ("The result is '" + str(x**y + "'")`

is missing a bracket

Comment: This.  You aren't closing the parentheses opened by `str(`.  Should be `str(x**y) + "'"` (all inside the outer parentheses of the `print` call).

Answer (score 0):

the recursive call is not optimal as if you keep it running there will be a stack overflow after multiple uses!

Rather do a loop in the main logic

```
while True:

    calc();
```

Comment: not the cause of the compile error but important to your learning